# Live USB+Xubuntu17.10 + Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377: network not working

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, atheros

Installed 17.10 on a stick via rufus for Lenovo 110s.
Seemingly hopefully a popup immediately on booting says "connections available, check network menu" (Ha
Try FF doesn't connect.
Go to network via system: No connections shown in network window. 
Help says run `network -admin`. 
Run in `network -admin` xterm : "No command network".

What should I do next ?

Comment: I would switch to Ubuntu 16.04.1 as there are some issues with 4.11+ kernels and Lenovos

Comment: *Thanks** @Jeremy31. I just switched from 16.04!